# Laravel Login Issue for multiple roles

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware, roles

I have added multiple roles authentication in laravel 8.6. Used common middleware for this but occurring issues for login.

i.e If i logged in as admin (role id 1) it will redirected successfully to dashboard. But if you logged out and login as user (role id 2) it will redirect to login page again and the on second time it will redirected to dashboard on second attempt.

I need solution for it.

Comment: Please copy and paste your middlewares code. Your question isn't clear enough without displaying your code.

Comment: On role 2 redirect to log in again seriously? You can not force a logged user to log in again?

Answer (score 0):

In your login controllers     `authenticated` method,

- If you are using `spatie/larave-permission` package

  ```
   $user = Auth::user();
   if ($user->hasRole('super-admin')) {
       return redirect()->route('dashboard');
   }

   if ($user->hasRole('admin')) {
       return redirect()->route('login');
   }
  ```
- If using self role middleware

  ```
   $user = Auth::user();

   if ($user->role_id === 1) {
       return redirect()->route('dashboard');
   }

   if ($user->role_id === 2) {
       return redirect()->route('login');
   }
  ```

But **you can not** force a logged-in user to log in again. What is your plan? I strongly advise you to try something else.